# Multiple foreign key relationships for one record in asp.net mvc, code-first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, code-first

I have a very simple question. I am new to ASP.NET MVC and very much confused about relationships while following code-first technique.

I have two model classes. I want to describe it as *one person can have many courses*.

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CourseId { get; set; }

   // public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses{ get; set; }

   /* I removed above line from model because it was not creating any Course Field in Db table of Person and added a third table */
}
```

In order to make a relationship I created another model class that contains Id of persons and repeating Id's of the course

```
public class ModelJoin
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ModelJoinId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Person")]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person{ get; set; }

    //One to many relationships 
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses{ get; set; }
}
```

So model join will have only two properties. I want to ask how we achieve this in a best way.

Value of courses will always be null so we can not add any course in it. Where in the code we will assign it a object?

There are a lot of questions on stackoverflow but no one describes it from scratch.

Is there any tutorial for add update delete tables with foreign keys.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: If one person can have many courses, then the `Person` table should not have course field. There should be a new table to store the PersonId and the CourseId.

Answer (score 1):

I think  you need many to many relationship as one student can be enrolled for many courses and one course can be taken by many students.

Look at this: 
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The course collection should be in the `Person` class, try this :

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
}
```

So for example if you want to add a person with a course.

```
var person = new Person();
var courses = new List<Course>();
courses.Add(new Course());
person.Courses = courses;
dbContext.Persons.Add(person);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Person.Courses is null, it will not allow to add